# node.js export module function

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I have a problem with node.js. I am creating a blog and I have two archives:
sessions.js users.js

in sessions.js :

```
function SessionsDAO(db) {
this.startSession = function(username, callback) {....}
}
module.exports.SessionsDAO = SessionsDAO;
```

in users.js

```
var Session = require('./sessions');
var s = new Session();
s.startSession(username);
```

but shows me error:

```
object is not a function
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` returns the `exports` object, so:

```
var SessionsDAO = require('./sessions').SessionsDAO;
var s = new SessionsDAO();
s.startSession(username);
```

Comment: thanks but problem now is:

        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: My best guess would be that you're not passing a callback to `startSession`, so you're getting that error when it tries to `callback()`.